# Get first array in object with length X

Tags: arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I am importing an excel file into a web app using `xlsx` library and each row in the excel sheet is stored into an object containing arrays with length equal to the number of cells in each row as shown below...

```js
onFileChange(event: any) {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */
      console.log(typeof binaryString)

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      console.log(workSheetName)
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      this.data = <Array>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1, blankrows: true }));


    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);

  }
```

trying this below

I am trying to make another function `getFirstMeaningfulRow` which would spit out the first row with a length >= 5 let's say, would a `for-loop` be the appropriate method by which to accomplish this?

````
using the `find` function
```typescript
getFirstMeaningfulRow() {
    console.log(this.data.find(meaningfulRow => this.data.length >= 5
````

spits out the first array that contains a string with more than five characters in it. 
Ex.

```
first row imported contains one element, a date MM/DD/YYY so console.log shows

["10 SEPTEMBER, 2019"]
 0: "10 SEPTEMBER, 2019"
```

I am trying to find the first array in the object with more than 5 elements in that array so that `console.log` would show:

```
['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4',...]
  0: 'item0'
  1: 'item1'
  2: 'item2'
  3: 'item3'
  4: 'item4'
     ...
```

Comment: You can use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first row with predicate `row.length >=5`.

Comment: @ford04 I tried this already but this spits out the first row with an array that has a string length of greater than 5 I am more concerned with finding the first array in the object of arrays with more than 5 elements see updated question, should've included that sorry

Comment: edited one more time for some formatting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intended to use `meaningfulRow` rather than `this.data`.

You're comparing the length of the array not the length of the element.

```
  getFirstMeaningfulRow() {
       console.log(this.data.find(x=> x.length >= 5))
   }
```